# Django Template short hand for loading and using static files

Tags: django, django-templates

For example to load a static image, I need to do that in template in two lines, like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "img/pro_pic.png" %}">
```

Is there any way to do that in one line?

```
<img src="{% staticLoad( "img/pro_pic.png" ) %}">
```

and a function somewhere that checks {% load staticfiles %} is there or not, if not it loads and all that? I also encourage time complexity discussion if it can be done!

Comment: why do you want this? what is the problem with django's default 2 lines?

Comment: Why would I write two line if I have the choice to write it in one line?

Comment: you dont write 2 lines basically, you load it only once and call only ``static`` the rest of the time. i dont see any reason to worry about this. better concentrate on other parts of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the [django.core.context_processors.static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django.core.context_processors.static) context process is included in the [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) setting so you can just write in your template:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/pro_pic.png">
```